# 3 strings with the same name - need to store in different columns in datatable

Tags: c#, database

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.xConnectionString);
 conn.Open();
 SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
 myCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT SerialNumber from Warranty");
 SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 int count = myReader.FieldCount;

 //Loop through webbrowser form
 while (myReader.Read())
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
           //Loop through Serial Numbers
           string result = myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
           //Iterate through x's Serial Checker 1 by 1
           webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").Focus();
           webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("serialCode").InnerText = result;
           webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("warrantySubmit").InvokeMember("Click");
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           //MessageBox.Show("TEST");
           //Get Base Warranty, Warranty Upgrade, and Priority Support
           foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "fluid-row Borderfluid")
                {
                     string record = el.InnerText;
                     //if record is the string to parse
                     var result1 = parseString(record);
                     //var result_string = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", r)).ToArray());
                     var strStartDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{0}", r)).ToArray());
                     var strEndDate = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{1}", r)).ToArray());
                     var strStatus = string.Join("", result1.ConvertAll(r => string.Format("{2}", r)).ToArray());
                     Thread.Sleep(500);
                     MessageBox.Show(strStartDate);
                     MessageBox.Show(strEndDate);
                     MessageBox.Show(strStatus);
                 }                    
               }
           }
```

The issue I have currently is that there are 3 div's in this html page that have "fluid-row Borderfluid" - Each div contains 3 things I want - "Start Date, End Date, and Status"

Thus, every loop I get 9 values but are stored only into 3 (strStartDate, strEndDate, strStatus) This would be fine if I am doing a MessageBox.Show but I am only doing that to test the results.

I want to store all 9 values into 9 separate columns in my data-table. Is there a way where I can say 'the first result back in strStartDate put here, the second result from strStartDate put here, and the third result from strStartDate put here'

I dont know if this exists or I am going about this all wrong. Would appreciate help.

**Update: My DataTable Structure**

I am using AccessDB and to spare some detail I have the following in 1 row:
OriginalXStartDate
OriginalXEndDate
OriginalXStatus
OriginalYStartDate
OriginalYEndDate
OriginalYStatus
OriginalZStartDate
OriginalZEndDate
OriginalZStatus

So I am trying to get strStartDate (which will have 3 values due to the 3 html div's) into these rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes."  It is done when you store the information into your database.  I don't know what database you are using, or your table design, so I can only focus on getting the values in a format you can reference later.

As an example, you could create a class MyClass to store the information from a div.  I kept to the string datatype as this was your example, however I would convert to DateTime and store that format and not string.  Up to you.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string startDate, string endDate, string status) 
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.status = status; 
    }

    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
 }
```

In your code (outside of your foreach loop), create an instance of a List using the MyClass class.

```
 List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

After you do your MessageBox.Show, add a new item to the list:

```
  myList.Add(new MyClass(strStartDate, strEndDate, strStatus);
```

After your loop, you have a list with three instances, each one has the three values.

Now, go to the database with your values. I don't know if you plan a table with three rows, each with three columns, or one table with nine columns, but either way you can get the data you want to store.

Comment: Yes I am planning on converting my dates to DateTime! - It wasnt working due to it having 3 dates at the same time I believe. And I see so basically I have to store it in a List Collection to store it temporarily? I have around 200 rows I need to do this too, will this overwrite the info it saves to the List or keep creating new instances?

Comment: The List object can grow as big as you want/need.  The Add method creates a new instance, so it's easier to use for variable length data than an Array type (for example).

You can also search lists to find content using LINQ; this might be helpful for you when you go to store it in your database.  Not sure since I don't know your data storage method

Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You have the following Table/Data Structure (as you mentioned):

```
OriginalXStartDate, OriginalXEndDate, OriginalXStatus, OriginalYStartDate, OriginalYEndDate, OriginalYStatus, OriginalZStartDate, OriginalZEndDate, OriginalZStatus
```

As Mark West mentioned, you could use a class to represent these columns.

Simply write the SQL to insert. I'm unfamiliar with AccessDB, but I assume you can do execute SQL against it.

```
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO dbo.<TABLE>(OriginalXStartDate, OriginalXEndDate, OriginalXStatus, OriginalYStartDate, OriginalYEndDate, OriginalYStatus, OriginalZStartDate, OriginalZEndDate, OriginalZStatus) VALUES(@OriginalXStartDate, @OriginalXEndDate, @OriginalXStatus, @OriginalYStartDate, @OriginalYEndDate, @OriginalYStatus, @OriginalZStartDate, @OriginalZEndDate, @OriginalZStatus)";

// Use Correct Data Types/Lengths
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, <dbConnection>);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalXStartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalXEndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalXStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalYStartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalYEndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalYStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalZStartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalZEndDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OriginalZStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

// From Mark West's solution, using a class (MyClass for example, stored in List<MyClass> myList
// Could use variables, loop, do error checking etc. I'm not for the sake of time
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalXStartDate"].Value = myList[0].StartDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalXEndDate"].Value = myList[0].EndDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalXStatus"].Value = myList[0].Status;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalYStartDate"].Value = myList[1].StartDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalYEndDate"].Value = myList[1].EndDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalYStatus"].Value = myList[1].Status;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalZStartDate"].Value = myList[2].StartDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalZEndDate"].Value = myList[2].EndDate;
cmd.Parameters["@OriginalZStatus"].Value = myList[2].Status;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```